# Why only one record after union?

Tags: sql, mysql, union

```
mysql> select count(id) total from applicants;
+-------+
| total |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(id) total from jobs;
+-------+
| total |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(id) total from applicants union select count(id) total from
jobs;
+-------+
| total |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Isn't there supposed to be two records with "0" as its value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Union All would give two statements. Union attempts to combine the entries, or rather, remove the duplicate rows.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) :

> **The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from
>   the result**. The optional DISTINCT
>   keyword has no effect other than the
>   default because it also specifies
>   duplicate-row removal. With the
>   optional ALL keyword, duplicate-row
>   removal does not occur and the result
>   includes all matching rows from all
>   the SELECT statements.

Which means that, with only `UNION`, if two lines have the same value, one of them will not be returned :

```
mysql> select 1 union select 1;
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But, if using `UNION ALL`, duplicates are not removed :

```
mysql> select 1 union all select 1;
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
| 1 |
+---+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

UNION removes duplicates.  Try UNION ALL instead.